# SUM of values grouped by datetime from 4 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

I have 4 different tables, each of them looks like this:

```
--------------------------------
|id|  value|           datetime|
--------------------------------
| 1| 2554.0|  26-08-20 14:36:15|
| .|      .|                   |
| .|      .|                   |
| .|      .|                   |
--------------------------------
```

What I need is quite simple, yet I am not exactly sure how I can achieve this.

I need to sum up each value that have same datetime in 4 different tables.

Example:

```
Time is: 26-08-20 14:36:15

Table 1: 2554.0; 
Table 2: 4143.0; 
Table 3: 9432.0; 
Table 4: 1662.0;
```

I should be able to get: 17791

Comment: I'd rather ask why you have 4 such similar tables?

Comment: @jarlh I have data collected from 4 different machines

Comment: If you can't load all data into one common table, at least create a view that UNION ALL the 4 current tables. Then you can "pretend" you have just one table.

Comment: ... and, if possible, add a `machine_id` column to put all of the data into the same table. Otherwise, imagine having thousands of machines : would you create a table for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`.  If you want *all* the values, then:

```
select datetime, sum(value)
from ((select id, value, datetime, 1 as which from table1) union all
      (select id, value, datetime, 2 as which from table2) union all
      (select id, value, datetime, 3 as which from table3) union all
      (select id, value, datetime, 4 as which from table4)
     ) t
group by datetime;
```

If you want only the values in all four tables, then add:

```
having count(distinct which) = 4
```

If you have no duplicates *within* each table, then you can use `join` to get the values in all tables:

```
select datetime, sum(value)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (datetime) join
     table3 t3
     using (datetime) join
     table4 t4
     using (datetime)
group by datetime;
```

This only returns `datetime` values in all four tables.  Unfortunately, if you want all values added up, MySQL does not support `full join`, so the `union all` method is more general -- and safer because it handles duplicates within each table.

Comment: I am sorry, but I forgot to mention that each table has a different name for value column

Comment: @Rey-0 . . . That doesn't matter in the first version.